# Issue with Homestead ssh

Tags: laravel, ssh, homestead

I'm trying to run homestead ssh but somewhere it fails to startup correctlty.

Here are 2 screenshots from my colleague pc and mine

[My pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nz2No.png)

[My colleague pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksY5j.png)

You can see on my colleague pc it has the lines "last login" and "vagrant@homestead:~$",
Those lines are missing in my homestead box.

Further if i query ls -a i see the following differences:

[My ls -a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrEGc.png)

[My colleagues ls -a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deB1T.png)

I hope that someone could help me,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Bug in Vagrant 2.0.1 on Windows, you can downgrade to Vagrant 2.0.0., or use a different console application. (This bug exists in git bash and a few others, but does not in http://cmder.net/).